# How to create custom option selection in android studio and store in back end

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[option selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzV3Y.jpg)

How to create similar effect in android studio and store in firebase

Comment: This is not an Android Studio issue, don't use the Android Studio tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is my XML file.

```
<menu android:id="@+id/new_game"
      android:icon="@drawable/red_no_bg"
      android:title="Home" />
<item android:id="@+id/email"
      android:icon="@drawable/red_no_bg"
      android:title="Email" />
<item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:icon="@drawable/red_no_bg"
      android:title="Visit Microsite" />
```

Here is my code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```